# How to get my OpenGL cube shaders to render properly?

Tags: c++, opengl, cube

I am trying to make a cube in my OpenGL project. My code for some reason is not rendering and I have no idea why. I tried to change the `glm::mat4` to `glm::mat4(1)`; but, it still doesn't work. Even though nothing draws, I am not getting any errors or warnings. All I see is a blank screen, but no cube.

main.cpp

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#define GLEW_STATIC
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include "Shader.h"
#include "SOIL2/SOIL2.h"
#include <glm/glm.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/matrix_transform.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/type_ptr.hpp>

using namespace std;

const GLint WIDTH = 800;
const GLint HEIGHT = 600;

nt main() {
    glfwInit();
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, GL_TRUE );

    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(WIDTH, HEIGHT,"Pemdas" , nullptr, nullptr);
    
    int screenWidth;
    int screenHeight;
    glfwGetFramebufferSize(window, &screenWidth, &screenWidth);
    
    if(nullptr == window) {
        cout << "Falled to create the window.";
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }
    
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
    
    if(GLEW_OK != glewInit()) {
        std::cout << "Failed to initialize window" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }
    
    glViewport(0, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight);
    
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
    
    Shader ourShader("Resources/Shaders/core.vs", "Resources/Shaders/core.frag");
    
    GLfloat vertices[] =
    {
        -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f, 0.0f,
        0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  1.0f, 0.0f,
        0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,  1.0f, 1.0f,
        0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,  1.0f, 1.0f,
        -0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f, 1.0f,
        -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f, 0.0f,
        
        -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f, 0.0f,
        0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f,  1.0f, 0.0f,
        0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  1.0f, 1.0f,
        0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  1.0f, 1.0f,
        -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f, 1.0f,
        -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f, 0.0f,
        
        -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  1.0f, 0.0f,
        -0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,  1.0f, 1.0f,
        -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f, 1.0f,
        -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f, 1.0f,
        -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f, 0.0f,
        -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  1.0f, 0.0f,
        
        0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  1.0f, 0.0f,
        0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,  1.0f, 1.0f,
        0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f, 1.0f,
        0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f, 1.0f,
        0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f, 0.0f,
        0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  1.0f, 0.0f,
        
        -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f, 1.0f,
        0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  1.0f, 1.0f,
        0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f,  1.0f, 0.0f,
        0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f,  1.0f, 0.0f,
        -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f, 0.0f,
        -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f, 1.0f,
        
        -0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f, 1.0f,
        0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,  1.0f, 1.0f,
        0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  1.0f, 0.0f,
        0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  1.0f, 0.0f,
        -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f, 0.0f,
        -0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f, 1.0f
    };
    
    GLint VAO;
    glGenVertexArrays( 1, &VAO );
    
    GLint VBO;
    glGenBuffers( 1, &VBO );   
    
    glBindVertexArray( VAO );
    
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof( vertices ), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 5 * sizeof(GLfloat), (GLvoid*)0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    
    glVertexAttribPointer(2, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 5 * sizeof(GLfloat), (GLvoid*)(3 * sizeof(GLfloat)));
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);
    
    glBindVertexArray(0);
    
    GLuint texture;
    glGenTextures(1, &texture);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
    
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
    
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    
    int width;
    int height;
    unsigned char* image = SOIL_load_image("Resources/Shaders/pexels-adrien-olichon-2931270.jpg", &width , &hight, 0, SOIL_LOAD_RGBA);
    
    glTexImage2D( GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0,GL_RGBA, width, hight, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, image);
    glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    SOIL_free_image_data(image);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
    
    glm::mat4 projection(1);
    projection = glm::perspective(45.0f, (GLfloat)screenWidth / (GLfloat)screenHeight, 0.1f, 1000.0f);
    
    while(!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {
        glfwPollEvents();
        
        glClearColor(0.2f, 0.3f, 0.3f, 1.0f);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        
        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
        glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(ourShader.Program, "ourTexture"), 0);
       
        ourShader.Use();
        
        glm::mat4 model(1);
        glm::mat4 view(1);
        model = glm::rotate(model, (GLfloat)glfwGetTime() * 1.0f, glm::vec3(0.5f, 1.0f, 0.0f));
        view = glm::translate(view, glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, -3.0f));
        
        GLint modelLoc = glGetUniformLocation(ourShader.Program, "model");
        GLint viewLoc = glGetUniformLocation(ourShader.Program, "view");
        GLint projLoc = glGetUniformLocation(ourShader.Program, "projection");
        
        glUniformMatrix4fv(modelLoc, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(model));
        glUniformMatrix4fv(viewLoc, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(view));
        glUniformMatrix4fv(projLoc, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(projection));
        
        glBindVertexArray(VAO);
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 36);
        glBindVertexArray(0);
        
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
    }
    
    glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &VAO );
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &VBO);
    
   
    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}
```

core.vs

```cpp
#version 400 core
layout (location = 0) in vec3 position;
layout (location = 2) in vec2 texCoord;

out vec2 TexCoord;
uniform mat4 model;
uniform mat4 view;
uniform mat4 projection;

void main() {
    gl_Position = model * view * projection * vec4(position, 1.0f);

    TexCoord = vec2(texCoord.x, 1.0 - texCoord.y);
}
```

core.frag

```cpp
#version 400 core

in vec2 TexCoord;

out vec4 color;

uniform sampler2D texture1;

void main() {
    color = texture(texture1, TexCoord);
}
```

Comment: The order of the matrix multiplications is wrong. It has to be `gl_Position = projection * view * model * vec4(position, 1.0f);`

Comment: I don’t know the reason but I know how to find out. Use this software: https://renderdoc.org/ (freeware). It captures stuff at the API boundary between your program and GPU API (including all resources used), replays these draw calls, allows to inspect resources bound to the pipeline, can inspect meshes both on input and after vertex/geometry/tessellation stages, and even allows to debug shaders.

Comment: @Rabbid76 it doesn't work still.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments the order of transformations is opposite from the matrix multiplication order. Also in your vertex shader you get an input attribute named `color` in `location=1` but i don't see `glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);` anywhere.

Also i would advice you to check for compilation errors in your shaders like this:

```
glGetShaderiv(vertex, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success);
        if (!success)
        {
            glGetShaderInfoLog(vertex, 512, NULL, infoLog);
            std::cout << "ERROR::SHADER::VERTEX::COMPILATION_FAILED\n" << infoLog << std::endl;
        };
```

Comment: I deleted the color attribute, because I don't need it,  but it still wont work. Thank you for helping out!